# Does the OpenVPN server have a maximum number of two simulated users?

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I have read that openvpn server only accepts two simultaneous connections to the VPN connection and that if you want to obtain more connections you would have to buy licenses.

I have read in various forums contradictions of this where the maximum number is not supposed to be two users per VPN.

Can someone with knowledge of OpenVPN confirm if this is really true? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what a "simulated user" is, but more than two users can connect to my OpenVPN server simo.

I just did it, here is a somewhat redacted log.

```
 Tue Jan 25 11:06:26 2022 [my ip goes here]:36597 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET][my ip goes here]:36597, sid=6cf19f7a efad9ffe
 Tue Jan 25 11:06:26 2022 [my ip goes here]:36597 peer info: IV_PLAT=linux
 Tue Jan 25 11:06:26 2022 [my ip goes here]:36597 Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
 Tue Jan 25 11:06:26 2022 [my ip goes here]:36597 [user1] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET][my ip goes here]:36597
 Tue Jan 25 11:06:26 2022 user1/[my ip goes here]:36597 MULTI: primary virtual IP for user1/[my ip goes here]:36597: 10.8.0.4
 Tue Jan 25 11:07:02 2022 [my ip goes here]:57523 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET][my ip goes here]:57523, sid=69b97549 40baabd4
 Tue Jan 25 11:07:02 2022 [my ip goes here]:57523 peer info: IV_PLAT=android
 Tue Jan 25 11:07:02 2022 [my ip goes here]:57523 Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
 Tue Jan 25 11:07:02 2022 [my ip goes here]:57523 [user2] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET][my ip goes here]:57523
 Tue Jan 25 11:07:02 2022 user2/[my ip goes here]:57523 MULTI: primary virtual IP for user2/[my ip goes here]:57523: 10.8.0.9
 Tue Jan 25 11:07:18 2022 [my ip goes here]:51017 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET][my ip goes here]:51017, sid=755ef9f6 7ed60567
 Tue Jan 25 11:07:18 2022 [my ip goes here]:51017 peer info: IV_PLAT=linux
 Tue Jan 25 11:07:18 2022 [my ip goes here]:51017 Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
 Tue Jan 25 11:07:18 2022 [my ip goes here]:51017 [user3] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET][my ip goes here]:51017
 Tue Jan 25 11:07:18 2022 user3/[my ip goes here]:51017 MULTI: primary virtual IP for user3/[my ip goes here]:51017: 10.8.0.5
```